# Detect whether a desktop application installed on clients system from a webpage

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, deeplink

I want to check from a webpage, if the desktop app installed on the user's machine, **IF** installed then open it to proceed **ELSE** send an installation link to the user.

There is an option for mobile apps like Universal link OR deep link, but they are only for mobile applications, can I do this somehow for desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

navigator.plugins is the keyword for you

Comment: can navigator.plugins detect desktop apps? didn't find any solution with navigator.plugins. can you please give me any documentation or tutorial?

Comment: really ??? I thought u want to check broswser app or addons ?
well if you want to check whether your computer have Call of Duty installed, then sorry you just can't

Comment: its simply impossible, mate :)

Comment: Maybe it's possible, slack is also doing similar working here https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking, click on 'Open #General' button, if you have the slack desktop app installed it will ask you top open slack app otherwise it will redirect you to website